# Why the data disappears after Docker Mysql 5.7 died

Tags: docker, mysql-5.7

A Docker Mysql5.7 is running in my cloud server, but when there are not clients connecting to the docker mysql5.7 a few days, it will die. The most terrible thing is that after I restarted with the docker restart mysql5.7 command, I found that the data stored in it disappeared, although I have configured the volume for it. Now *all the databases and data* I have created have disappeared.

Can someone please help me?

I will appreciate your assistance.

Here are the logs of my docker mysql5.7 before it died:

```
2023-05-22T02:54:14.220747Z 1672 [Note] Got an error reading communication packets
2023-05-22T02:54:16.896040Z 1673 [Warning] IP address '119.51.93.34' has been resolved to the host name '34.93.51.119.adsl-pool.jlccptt.net.cn', which resembles IPv4-address itself.
2023-05-22T04:03:35.751249Z 1674 [Warning] Hostname 'zg-0512b-112.stretchoid.com' does not resolve to '107.170.249.64'.
2023-05-22T04:03:35.751271Z 1674 [Note] Hostname 'zg-0512b-112.stretchoid.com' has the following IP addresses:
2023-05-22T04:03:35.751278Z 1674 [Note]  - 127.0.0.1
2023-05-22T04:03:36.012149Z 1674 [Note] Got an error reading communication packets
2023-05-22T04:52:13.240439Z 1675 [Warning] IP address '122.136.45.239' has been resolved to the host name '239.45.136.122.adsl-pool.jlccptt.net.cn', which resembles IPv4-address itself.
2023-05-22T04:52:13.240557Z 1675 [Note] Got an error reading communication packets
2023-05-22T04:52:13.308186Z 1676 [Warning] IP address '122.136.45.239' has been resolved to the host name '239.45.136.122.adsl-pool.jlccptt.net.cn', which resembles IPv4-address itself.
2023-05-22T04:59:30.216990Z 1677 [Warning] IP address '34.78.249.41' has been resolved to the host name '41.249.78.34.bc.googleusercontent.com', which resembles IPv4-address itself.
2023-05-22T04:59:30.479466Z 1677 [Note] Got an error reading communication packets
2023-05-22T05:23:31.875888Z 1678 [Note] Aborted connection 1678 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'root' host: '' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2023-05-22T06:50:44.702235Z 1679 [Note] Got an error reading communication packets
2023-05-22T06:57:05.449753Z 1680 [Warning] Hostname 'zg-1220d-1.stretchoid.com' does not resolve to '198.199.114.53'.
2023-05-22T06:57:05.449771Z 1680 [Note] Hostname 'zg-1220d-1.stretchoid.com' has the following IP addresses:
2023-05-22T06:57:05.449777Z 1680 [Note]  - 127.0.0.1
2023-05-22T06:57:05.449886Z 1680 [Note] Got packets out of order
2023-05-22T07:39:58.531102Z 1681 [Warning] Host name 'ip6.50-31-21.static.steadfastdns.net' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2023-05-22T07:39:58.709479Z 1681 [Note] Got an error reading communication packets
2023-05-22T07:42:01.898715Z 1682 [Note] Got packets out of order
2023-05-22T07:47:19.691103Z 1683 [Warning] Hostname 'internettl.org' does not resolve to '104.152.52.143'.
2023-05-22T07:47:19.691126Z 1683 [Note] Hostname 'internettl.org' has the following IP addresses:
2023-05-22T07:47:19.691134Z 1683 [Note]  - 162.255.119.131
2023-05-22T07:47:29.696695Z 1683 [Note] Got timeout reading communication packets
2023-05-22T08:10:04.386810Z 1684 [Note] Got packets out of order
2023-05-22T08:12:49.459379Z 1685 [Warning] IP address '60.16.16.104' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2023-05-22T08:12:49.459498Z 1685 [Note] Got an error reading communication packets
2023-05-22T09:18:29.766266Z 1687 [Warning] Host name 'adsl.inet-telecom.org' could not be resolved: No address associated with hostname
2023-05-22T09:18:59.923489Z 1688 [Warning] Host name 'adsl.inet-telecom.org' could not be resolved: No address associated with hostname
2023-05-22T09:19:00.778808Z 1689 [Warning] Host name 'adsl.inet-telecom.org' could not be resolved: No address associated with hostname
2023-05-22T09:19:05.401630Z 1690 [Warning] Host name 'adsl.inet-telecom.org' could not be resolved: No address associated with hostname
2023-05-22T09:19:38.244223Z 1691 [Warning] Host name 'adsl.inet-telecom.org' could not be resolved: No address associated with hostname
2023-05-22T09:19:41.017323Z 1692 [Warning] Host name 'adsl.inet-telecom.org' could not be resolved: No address associated with hostname
2023-05-22T09:19:43.619895Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2023-05-22T09:19:43.619928Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2023-05-22T09:19:43.619937Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620096Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620623Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620640Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620644Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620648Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620652Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620686Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620695Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620709Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620713Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620716Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620719Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620723Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620726Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620729Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620731Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620734Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620737Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620741Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620744Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620747Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620751Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620754Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620758Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620761Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620764Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620767Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620771Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620774Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620777Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620780Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620783Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620786Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620789Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620792Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620795Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620798Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620801Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620805Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2023-05-22T09:19:43.620860Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2023-05-22T09:19:43.621352Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2023-05-22T09:19:43.721602Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2023-05-22T09:19:43.721972Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 230522  9:19:43
2023-05-22T09:19:45.237608Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 79691012
2023-05-22T09:19:45.238275Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2023-05-22T09:19:45.238297Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2023-05-22T09:19:45.238304Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2023-05-22T09:19:45.238310Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2023-05-22T09:19:45.238314Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2023-05-22T09:19:45.238473Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2023-05-22T09:19:45.239406Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: can you share your command or docker compose file, you used to create the mysql container ?

Comment: Here is the command: docker run -p 3306:3306 --name mysql5.7 -v /mydata/mysql/log:/var/log/mysql -v /mydata/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql -v /mydata/mysql/conf:/etc/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 -d mysql:5.7

Comment: have you used docker system prune command or docker image rm command ?

Comment: I haven't used these commands. I only ran the command of docker restart mysql5.7 after discovering it was dead.